# Excel - how do I use VBA to select a dropdown list item?

Tags: excel, vba, drop-down-menu

I have a large Excel spreadsheet and need to provide some automated sanity checks by selecting options from a couple of dropdown lists which have directly defined options i.e. in data validation values are entered directly instead of using a cell range.
I have tried writing a value to the cell but it is protected from direct writes.
I could add a cell range instead of directly defined values if need be.
Everything else works, opening the target spreadsheet, writing other values, reading back etc.
Thanks

Comment: If the cell is protected, you can't change it without unprotecting the sheet.

Comment: Thanks, I have removed the protection and cna modify the cell.

Answer (score 0):

Removing the protection worked.
The target spreadsheet takes a few seconds to perform calculations each time and I have not had to add any waits or status checks before reading the values back from other cells.